# Oracle SQL Select Rows where column with date is at most one hour before now ( sysdate )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

| invoice_number | creation_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-06T10:38:37.000+00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-02-06T10:49:34.000+00:00 |

I want to fetch rows only where `creation_Date` is 1 hours ago or less, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  creation_date >= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one;

... where creation_Date>sysdate - interval '1' hour

Comment: This may be wrong as it does not consider that `SYSDATE` may be in a different time zone to the OP's timestamps (which are in the UTC time zone).